# Bind complex dictionary to a combobox DisplayMember with WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, dictionary, combobox, bindingsource

Is it possible to bind a complex Dictionary to a combobox displaymember?

I have been able to use "Key" and "Value" for basic Dictionary without any issue but having issues with a class.

sample class:

```
public class someClass
{
     public int MessageId {get;set;}
     public int CustomerId {get;set;
     public string Message {get;set;}
}
```

WCF method:

```
public Dictionary<int, someClass> GetCustomerMessages(int customerId)
```

client side code:

```
BindingSource _bsCustomerMessages = new BindingSource();
_bsCustomerMessages.DataSource = client.GetCustomerMessages(1);

lbCustomerMessages.ValueMember = "Key";
lbCustomerMessages.DisplayMember = "Value";
lbCustomerMessages.DataSource = _bsCustomerMessages;
```

I have also tried using the class member:

```
lbCustomerMessages.DisplayMember = "Message";
```

I saw in another answer someone had mentioned to override the Message with ToString, but putting that definition in the WCF Service class isn't pushing the service reference.

In the watch window I can see in the _bsCustomerMessages.List[0].Value the data is being pulled.

I know I can get around it by creating additional methods in the WCF service but would like to know if this is possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is that "Message" is not a property of Dictionary, you're trying to access a nested property, so it should be "Value.Message";

Comment: Ahh, I was so close.  That was it, thanks for the fast answer!

Comment: The behavior of this seems really strange.  It doesn't seem like the listBox likes this type of binding at all.  i'm getting some really inconsistent results.  Sometimes it binds properly, but then it binds the class as an item in the listbox.

Comment: well, that's really strange, it should not do that, are you sure you're not changing the DisplayMember anywhere else?